# Html5 javascript and css with Xamarin

Tags: javascript, html, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am writing a native cross platform application using Xamarin forms. But i am having one page with a Web view where i need to render an existing HTML5 page. The existing HTML 5 page have JavaScript and Css as well . I wanted to port these files in Xamarin forms application instead of hosting in a Server.How can i solve this scenario?

Thanks in Advance

**Note**

I am aware that we can use Razor engine to load HTML.But seems it is not working with HTML5 js and css combination.

Comment: What exactly will the HTML 5, JS, and CSS do in terms or functionality with the device? For example, will it need to play videos or use any of the devices features (camera, video, etc.)? I ask because depending on how crazy the HTML 5 page might be, you may need to create a custom `WebView` renderer.

Comment: Did not edit my above comment in time, but if the HTML 5 page is not doing anything too fancy, then I suggest you follow Xamarin's guide [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/#Local_HTML_Content) and/or tell us any issues you faced with following those instructions.

Comment: @hvaughan3  i am using HTML5 to read and display CBZ,PDF and EPub files.Specially, CBZ files contain set of images. I am using HTML5 and JS  since there is no any cross platform ,mono based library to read cbz,pdf and epub files (as far as i know) .Thus i should to use HTML5. Eg like this  https://dzone.com/articles/how-i-built-html5-comic-book.

Comment: Did you have issues using Xamarin's guide that I linked to in the last comment?

Comment: @hvaughan3 Yes page is not rendering properly.I am wondering WebView  whether it fully supports  Html  5.If i removed some Html 5 elements  from html it is rendering properly.

Comment: Unfortunately it depends on the type of device. Android WebViews will support different HTML 5 features than iOS WebViews will be default. Though you can usually compensate and/or code around the issues. What kind of things are not rendering and on what types of devices? Maybe add some code to your question and point out exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself how complex are each of the possible solutions (a) short-term and (b) long-term:

- Write brand new code in XF
- Use WebView to show a static copy of your HTML
- Use WebView to show a your remote page
- Open a link to your page in Safari

The list above starts with high upfront cost and ends with lowest upfront cost, the long term cost can vary significantly: do you want to update your app whenever your web page's design changes; is the web page fairly complex; will you be using it for tracking users;.... the list goes on.

Without specifics it's hard to guess what's the best way to deal with your issue.

Assuming it's *really* a toss-up I'd go with XF all the way, re-implement that page's functionality in XAML because it will allow future development to be self-contained - you should reduce the code's dependencies as much as possible, that includes dependencies that don't show up compile-time. It can be painful for a team to maintain an app when they depend on another team to fix/update something.

Comment: .Thank you .I am aware about the disadvantages of having a HTML in Xamarin.But in my case, only one page will contain HTML which is never going to change in future.I am using HTML5  here bz of the limitation of libraries available for PCL(Supporting xamarin) for reading CBZ,CBR ,EPUB and etc files(Please see my comments for @hvaughan3.) If you know such a library please let me know.I found it is easy in HTML5.

Comment: If you're only viewing files then try using a `XF.WebView` without any fancy JS or HTML, just send the file to the WebView (I've done that with PDF) and opt out of using any fancy JS controls until your users ask for it (have they?). It's not worth supporting anything that isn't too important

Comment: Petrove. You mean XF.WebView can simply render the PDF without any HTML?How  can we load pdf in WebView without HTML?Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Yes, you can. The linked document is for iOS but I'm sure it works on android too. See file types at the link:  https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/web_view/load_non-web_documents/